# Acute set in three-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Prove that every set of more than $8$ points in the three-dimensional space determines at least one obtuse angle.

I'm aware that the generalization of this question for $\mathbb{R}^d$ was proved in 1962 by Danzer and Grunbaum. But I'm interested in a prove just for the case $d=3$ using convex polytopes or similar arguments to the case $d=2$. Anyone know about such proof? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have 'the answer' but, take the case of a cube where all angles are right. Adding any point to this system may make and acute angle with some points but it will be the vertex of at least one obtuse angle in the system.